# Vista de datos php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, mvc, poo

Tengo un problema al mostrar los datos en la vista, me explico, tengo un formulario de modificación de datos, los cuales editan y actualizan los datos de la base de datos sin problemas, pero cuando regreso a la vista para mostrar todos los datos de la tabla, no me muestra ninguno de los previamente editados  (valga la aclaración: si se almacenan los datos editados en la db y solo me muestra los datos que inserte desde el script sql), ni cuando le doy a actualizar, ni refrescando el servidor. Estoy realizando una web POO MVC con PHP y mysqli. Algo que este haciendo mal??
Es esta tabla a la cual realizo la consulta.

```
CREATE TABLE estudiante (
    rude VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombres VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(30),
    grado ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') NOT NULL,
    paralelo ENUM('A', 'B') NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
/* --------------------------*/
```

y tengo otra tabla asistencia:

```
CREATE TABLE asistencia (
asistencia_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
fecha_asistencia DATE NOT NULL,
tipo_asistencia ENUM('P','F','A','L') NOT NULL,
rude VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (rude) REFERENCES estudiante(rude)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Para actualizar los datos uso la siguiente consulta:

```
REPLACE INTO estudiante SET 
        rude = '$rude', 
        nombres = '$nombres', 
        apellidos = '$apellidos',
        telefono = '$telefono', 
        grado = '$grado', 
        paralelo = '$paralelo'
```

Para obtener los datos a la db uso lo siguiente:

```
public function get( $es = '' ) {

    $this->query = ($es != '') 
        ?"SELECT es.rude, es.nombres, es.apellidos, es.telefono, es.grado, es.paralelo
        FROM estudiante as es
        INNER JOIN asistencia as a
        on es.rude = a.rude
        WHERE es.rude = '$es' ORDER BY es.rude ASC"
        :"SELECT *
        FROM estudiante as es
        INNER JOIN asistencia as a
        on es.rude = a.rude";

    $this->get_query();

    $num_rows = count($this->rows);

    $data = array();

    foreach ($this->rows as $key => $value) {
        array_push($data, $value);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: añade las consultas SQL que ejecutas desde PHP de otro modo imposible ver que falla

Comment: toda la información necesaria para mejorar tu publicación añadela a la pregunta, dándole click en editar y pega este contenido

Comment: Listo, soy nuevo aqui... aprendo a utilizar las herramientas :P

Comment: Ya lo solucione, el error radica en mi pobre manera de ver el codigo... solo queria obtener los valores de estudiante y estaba consultando valores de asistencia, la consulta correcta era:
      SELECT * FROM estudiante WHERE rude = '$es'

Comment: De todos modos tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Esta variable que pasas tal cual en la consulta: `= '$es'` puede ser manipulada por un usuario mal intencionado, incluyendo código dañino para la base de datos e incluso para el sistema / servidor. Cuando sea posible lee aquí mismo sobre lo que es la **Inyección SQL** y cómo evitarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación y ya empece a leer sobre el tema que mencionaste.